# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation (chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call a function in JavaScript when a user clicks a button (`onclick="Website.submit()"`), but my code doesn't work.

I am getting this error in Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

In Chrome, this line is highligted in `jquery.js` as the source of the error:

```
// If value is a function, invoke it and return its value

value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value );
```

More detailed error on the developer panel's Console tab (F12):

[image: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation in Chrome]

Here is the code:

```js
var Website = {

  submit: function () {

    var stap1 = $('#stap1').val();
    var stap2 = $('#stap2').val();
    var stap3 = $('#stap3').val();
    var letop = $('#letop').val();

    if (stap1.length == 0) {
      $('#error2').show();
      $('#the_error2').html('Je moet alle velden invullen om door te gaan.');

      $('#stap1').css({
        'border-width': '1px',
        'border-color': 'red'
      });
    }

    if (stap2.length == 0) {
      $('#error2').show();
      $('#the_error2').html('Je moet alle velden invullen om door te gaan.');

      $('#stap2').css({
        'border-width': '1px',
        'border-color': 'red'
      });
    }

    if (stap3.length == 0) {
      $('#error2').show();
      $('#the_error2').html('Je moet alle velden invullen om door te gaan.');

      $('#stap3').css({
        'border-width': '1px',
        'border-color': 'red'
      });
    }

    if (letop.length == 0) {
      $('#error2').show();
      $('#the_error2').html('Je moet alle velden invullen om door te gaan.');

      $('#letop').css({
        'border-width': '1px',
        'border-color': 'red'
      });
    }

    if (stap1.length !== 0 && stap2.length !== 0 && stap3.length !== 0 && letop.length !== 0) {

      $.post(General.url + "/pages/website_check.php", {
        naam: naam,
        subdomein: subdomein,
        stap1: stap1,
        stap2: stap2,
        stap3: stap3,
        letop: letop
      }, function (result) {

        if (result == 1) {
          $('#error2').show();
          $('#the_error2').html('Deze naam is al in gebruik. Ga snel terug en kies een andere.');

          $('#error').show();
          $('#the_error').html('Deze naam is al in gebruik. Kies een andere.');

          $('#naam').css({
            'border-width': '1px',
            'border-color': 'red'
          });

        } else {
          if (result == 2) {
            $('#error2').show();
            $('#the_error2').html('Dit subdomein is al in gebruik. Ga snel terug en kies een andere.');

            $('#error').show();
            $('#the_error').html('Dit subdomein is al in gebruik. Kies een andere.');

            $('#subdomein').css({
              'border-width': '1px',
              'border-color': 'red'
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }

};
```

Comment: Are you posting to a different domain than the script was loaded from?

Comment: Nope it is the same General.url gives me my own localhost.

Comment: What is on and around line 128 of general.js?

Comment: I wanted to ask the same as Alex Wayne. It seems like the source of the problem is around the `$.post()` method, but we should know more details. You should also debug whether `General.url` is not out of the scope, and that it has a valid value which is acceptable here (a string, and it is not an object for example). `naam` and `subdomein` variables should also be debugged.

Answer (score 0):

just comment the line 
value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value );
in jQuery.js.

i.e.

```
add = function( key, value ) {
        // If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
        //value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value );
        s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( value );
    };
```